# where do i get .mdb and .pst file on my control station

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

I need help from you again, The customer has asked to  locate for .mdb and .pst files .All this is required for the migration process.I 'm not involved while the migration is going on but I 've been asked to look for .mdb and .pst files celerra NAS.

Any linux guys-please help me! since control station is totally linux based

Can you help me know - how do i do a scan for these two files from my control station?...A quick help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried - dir *.pst /s
           find /root/of/filesystem/to/scan  -name '*.pst'
           find / -name '*.pst' -ls

nothing is working out .The customer claims somebody did run it for them b'fore.Let me if i can get this any way from celerra control station.

Any linux guys-please help me! since control station is totally linux based

Answer (score 2):

On a linux system find is what you'll want to use....

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Comment: its not finding those.  Is there any other way i can locate?

Answer (score 2):

Try `-iname` instead of `-name` to get case insensitive matching, maybe the file is named OUTLOOK.PST

```
find /root/of/filesystem/to/scan -iname '*.pst'
```